# ¿Cómo acelerar la búsqueda de valores que coinciden en un segundo marco de datos en una iteración línea por línea de un primer marco de datos?

Tags: python, dataframe, python-3.7, rendimiento, iteradores

Tengo una dataframe de respuesta a encuestas para cual cada una tiene un `code`:

`df`

```
    code    item_stamp          question_name   question_type   scorable_question   subquestion_name    stage    products_stamp product_ID  answer_name respondent_id   answers_identity    answer  Test Code
0   006032  '173303553131045'   Age group       single          1.0                 NaN                 Screener NaN            <NA>        31 - 45 '173303561331047'   '11357427731020'    2   6032
1   006032  '173303553131045'   Age group       single          1.0                 NaN                 Screener NaN            <NA>        31 - 45 '173303561431047'   '11357427731020'    2   6032
```

Tengo tambien una dataframe con los tipos de cada encuestas que se identifian con `Test Code` :

`df_synthesis_clean`

```
    Country Country Code    Category            Application                 Gender  Program         Evaluation Stage                    Context Packaging Code  Test Code   Test Completion Agency Deadline Product Type    Line Extension  Dosage  Fragrance House_ID  product_ID  Liking Mean Liking Scale    Olfactive Family    Olfactive Subfamily OLFACTIVE CLUSTER EASY FRESH TEXTURED WARM  SIGNATURE   QUALIFICATION VERT ORANGE ROUGE TOP SELLER  TOP TESTER
0   France  FR              Fine Men Fragrances Perf/Edt/A-Shave/Col (FM)   M       scent hunter    clst - sniff - on glass ball jar    Blind   NaN             3879         4/15/2016 0:00 NaN Market Product  EDT 12.0    817.0   8082451124  5.55    0 to 10 WOODY   Floral  TEXTURED WARM   NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   USA     US              Fine Men Fragrances Perf/Edt/A-Shave/Col (FM)   M       scent hunter    clst - sniff - on glass ball jar    Blind   NaN             3855         4/15/2016 0:00 NaN Market Product  EDT 12.0    817.0   8082451124  4.88    0 to 10 WOODY   Floral  TEXTURED WARM   NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Quiero añadir una columna sobre el tipo de Programa que causó la respuesta (Flash o no flash)

Tengo el id de la prueba en df y el tipo de prueba en df_synthesis_clean

```
for _, row in df.iterrows():
  # Miraré en la tabla df_synthesis_clean para ver si la fila['code'] corresponde a un Código de Prueba
  # Tengo que poner iloc 0 porque un estudio corresponde a varios productos probados pero las respuestas no tienen  
  program = df_synthesis_clean.loc[df_synthesis_clean['Test Code'] == row['code']].iloc[0]['Program']
  row['Program'] = program
```

Lamentablemente tengo más de **tres millones de líneas** en `df` entonces es por eso por lo que lleva muchooo tiempo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pareciera que lo que estás necesitando es un `left join` algo bastante fácil y rápido de resolver si los datos estuvieran en una base de datos, pero, aún estando en pandas puedes hacer algo similar mediante `merge()` evitando así el loop. En primer lugar, las columnas por las que se relacionan ambos `dataframe` deben ser consistentes en cuanto al tipo de dato, en tu caso pareciera que `code` es una cadena y `Test code` es numérico, por lo que hay que empezar por aquí:

```
df.code = pd.to_numeric(df.code)
```

Y luego simplemente el `merge` con algunos accesorios para solo quedarnos con la columna `Program`:

```
result = pd.merge(df, df_synthesis_clean[['Test Code','Program']] , how="left", left_on="code", right_on="Test Code").drop(columns= ['Test Code'])
```

Cuidado, el `merge()` termina generando una copia, en este caso de `df`, eventualmente podrías intentar el `merge` pero recuperando únicamente la columna `Program`:

```
df['Program'] = pd.merge(df[['code']], df_synthesis_clean[['Test Code','Program']] , how="left", left_on="code", right_on="Test Code").drop(columns= ['code', 'Test Code'])
```